# Prove this integral related to the Ising model

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I came across this integral when learning the Ising model. Without external field Onsager's solution of a 2D square lattice with $J_2=0$ should equal the solution of a 1D Ising model, which leads to this

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\ln \left(\cosh 2K-\sinh 2K\cos\theta\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta=4\pi\ln\cosh K
$$
where $K\in\mathbb{R}$. I tested this integral numerically using Mathematica and it holds. But I want to prove it.

I tried splitting the LHS to

$$
2\pi\ln\cosh2K+\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(1-\tanh 2K\cos\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta
$$
and expanding the log function using Taylor series, but then the integration result became a complicated series

$$
-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n}\frac{2\pi}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\tanh^{2n}2K
$$
which does not easily relate to the RHS. Anyone has better idea?  Ising model is famous so this may have been done long ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will assume $K$ is real and positive.

Let $c = \cosh K$ and $s = \sinh K$. 
Notice $\cosh(2K) = c^2+s^2$ and $\sinh(2K) = 2sc$.
The integral at hand $\mathcal{I}$ equals to

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{I} 
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \log(c^2+s^2 - 2sc\cos\theta) d\theta
= \int_0^{2\pi} \log((c -s e^{i\theta})(c - s e^{-i\theta})) d\theta\\
&= 2\Re\left[\int_0^{2\pi} \log(c - se^{i\theta}) d\theta\right]
\end{align}
$$
Change variable to $z = e^{i\theta}$, the integral inside the bracket can be rewritten as a contour integral over the unit circle.

$$\mathcal{I} = 4\pi\Re\left[\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} \log(c - sz) \frac{dz}{z}\right]$$

Notice $c > s > 0$, the function $\log(c - sz)$ is entire over some open circle
the contains the closed unit disk. By [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula), we get
$$\mathcal{I} = 4\pi\Re\left[
\log(c- s\cdot 0))\right] =  4\pi\log(c) = 4\pi\log(\cosh K)$$

Comment: . . . nice ! . .